# INF Install Failure When Installing Visual Basic 6 Run-time SP 6 on Windows XP

Tags: vb6

I am trying to install the Visual Basic 6 run-time SP 6 on Windows XP.  After I decompress the installer to the Desktop and run it I get the following error, "INF Install Failure".  What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 2):

This might happen if you're not an administrator.